# wget put all prerequisites in flat subdirectory, but not root page?

Tags: wget, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get wget to save a page + prerequisites in a format resembling that of a web browser:

```
article.html
article_files/img.jpg
article_files/script.js
```

I am able to get almost this behavior, but `article.html` is inside `article_files`. Is this possible? My incomplete command is this:

```
wget  \
    --page-requisites \
    --html-extension  \
    --convert-links \
    --span-hosts \
    --restrict-file-names=windows \
    --no-directories \
    --directory-prefix=`basename $url` \
    $url
```

Is there an option to save the root page to a directory above all the prerequisites?